# Have making worker standards part of trade deals been tried?

Tags: trade, labor-policies

From an [article](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/toronto/migrant-march-yonge-and-dundas-sunday-1.6969787) linked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/canada/comments/16lkeql/migrant_march_for_permanent_residency_fills/), comments seem fairly unhappy with immigrants asking for rights as residency. Comments saying they should go back, no one invited them, baffled how they got to the country in the first place, etc. The article makes it clear these are people who are temporary workers, who don't have a path to stay longer or permanently, and it's been considered a [breeding ground for slavery by a UN official](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/toronto/migrant-march-yonge-and-dundas-sunday-1.6969787). Popular comments don't make comments on that (of course with temporary statuses available, any who leave will be replaced), nor alternatives. I'm not clear how people can be ok with (and depend on) resources, products, and labor coming from elsewhere but not people, unless they are actually supporting what the [UN official](https://www.reddit.com/r/london/comments/163gty0/domestic_slaves_rescued_from_londons_richest/?rdt=35832) [is concerned about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvrPH29O8wk). Comments seemed appalled by slavery, but also separately by the march that seeks to end such slavery.

I know in the EU, things like trade, democracy, and movement of people are part of the member requirements. I'm not sure how much labor standards are part of it. But this would seem a way to appeal to people who don't want foreigners competing for work, make workers standards part of trade deals so they have less appeal to come in the first place. Then also freedom of movement as part of the trade deals, like the EU, would be easier to include also, if people aren't forced to move by economic hardship. I've seen articles talk about this subject, but most are older, and I'm not sure I've seen cases of implementations.

Comment: With all due respect, I think you are mistaken about the issue, which is people entering the country illegally and then wanting all the rights and privileges of those who entered legally. People are not (or should not be) articles of trade or equivalent to fungible goods, nor are their rights.

Comment: -1 for the rant about Canada that’s unrelated to the question.

Comment: The comments are about stuff like: After living undocumented in Canada for six years, Jane says she wants permanent residency so she can get a good job and be treated equally." These are not temporary workers, but illegal immigrants.

Comment: It's not unrelated, it's about why the question is necessary. And no, y'all are just as incorrect as the comments there. It's about temporary workers who don't have a path to citizenship. Some try to work something out after, and remain undocumented. Like why are people baffled on how someone from Uganda got there.  https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2019/04/real-immigration-crisis-people-overstaying-their-visas/587485/

Comment: @user14094230 isn't that article about illegal immigrants (via illegal entrance or overstaying visa), which is what Wastrel is saying?

Comment: It's about how most people are just overstaying, i.e. not entering illegally, as Wastrel is saying. And the people were asking for rights for such people, such as to avoid what the UN person was talking about.

Comment: They are trying to avoid stuff like this https://www.reddit.com/r/london/comments/163gty0/domestic_slaves_rescued_from_londons_richest/?rdt=35832

Comment: Can you link to that UN person statement?  And can you use other sources than Reddit, please?  I upvoted the question, it's a good one about trade - and rich-country worker perceptions has a huge impact on signing future trade deals and populism.  But it requires some better background framing than some random comments on Reddit.

Comment: I added the direct link to the article, which is linked in the reddit post. The other reddit post has an embedded news video. I added that direct link also, if people don't want to follow links in reddits

Comment: @JonathanReez: TBH I'm not sure what the whole body of the Q has to do with the title... The 2nd para talks about the EU, which is much more than a trade deal. The OP then says "I'm not sure how much labor standards are part of it."

Comment: @Fizz EU has special cases with the quasi-EU states. Basically the EFTA trade deal, granting free movement of goods, imposes many EU laws onto its non EU members (Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway, and Switzerland). This includes, for example, worker health and safety like Directive 2019/983 on carcinogen exposure at work.

Answer (score 14):

Yes these are very common. See the International Labour Organization's [Labour Provisions in Trade Agreements Hub](https://www.ilo.org/LPhub/).

Comment: I would of course note that residency rights are usually not a part of such trade agreements - and countries like Saudi Arabia or UAE wisely avoid granting permanent residency to low-skilled workers.

Comment: @JonathanReez And treat them horribly in slavery-like conditions...

Comment: @Gantendo it's better than staying at home without a job.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, because taking the lead from Dubai and Saudi about how to treat foreign workers is what we ought to do.

Answer (score 5):

Well...

Yes and no.  Trade deals can often include them, but I am unsure how constraining they are on the various parties.

Let's take the [Comprehensive and Progressive Agreement for Trans-Pacific Partnership (CPTPP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehensive_and_Progressive_Agreement_for_Trans-Pacific_Partnership):  membership is:  Australia, Brunei, Canada, Chile, Japan, Malaysia, Mexico, New Zealand, **Peru**, Singapore, and **Vietnam**.

Here's the [Australian bit on the CPTPP labor provisions](https://www.dfat.gov.au/trade/agreements/in-force/cptpp/outcomes-documents/cptpp-outcomes-labour) :

> Building on internationally-recognised labour rights (freedom of association, collective bargaining, elimination of compulsory labour, abolition of child labour, and elimination of discrimination in respect of employment and occupation), **CPTPP Parties are required to have laws governing acceptable conditions of work relating to minimum wages, hours of work and occupational health and safety.** CPTPP Parties will, where appropriate, liaise and collaborate with international organisations such as the ILO or APEC.
>
> CPTPP Parties recognise that it is inappropriate to encourage trade or investment by weakening the protections of labour laws or their enforcement. Accordingly, **the Labour Chapter prohibits CPTPP Parties from weakening the protections afforded to workers under their labour laws, or from failing to enforce them in a manner affecting trade and investment.** The Chapter also promotes initiatives to discourage the importation of goods produced by forced or compulsory labour, including child labour.

**Now, color me cynical, but I highly doubt that Vietnam and Peru have, as a result of the CFTPP, "leveled up" their labor laws to the extent of the others.  They can't, they're poorer countries** (with iffy political frameworks in any case).  They would probably refuse to sign up for the trade agreement if they were really pushed too hard.

As a comment puts it nicely:

> "required to have laws" doesn't necessarily mean that the laws are as progressive as in the rich countries.

So, what you are probably seeing is trade agreements with some, welcome, obligations towards workers for some of the laggards, within reason.  But well short of equalizing pay and benefits.  The same way that NAFTA did not result in Mexican auto factory workers being paid at US rates.  Despite very lofty sounding goals in the [NAFTA labor chapter](http://www.sice.oas.org/trade/nafta/labor-c1.asp).

What you are asking for is likely not achievable with trade agreements, as it would be unrealistic to fully align workers in poor countries with richer countries.  That would negate the point of trade in the first place, and it would leave worker in poor countries worse off, without those trade-dependent jobs.  What a trade agreement, can and should do, is to shut the door on the worst abuses and motivate compliance via risk of losing the trade benefits.

Another reason to be more careful about worker impact is that workers, in rich countries, vote.  Too many agreements without worker protection means that it will become harder and harder to pass trade agreements.  Which is why a trade agreement should also motivate countries to figure out transition plans for their own workers impacted by the new competition.

---

The second thing is that many of the immigrants in your question probably aren't that impacted by trade agreements in the first place - if they were and had a good job at home, they'd stay there.  A first group, refugees will come from really poor countries, which probably don't have fancy schmancy trade agreements with rich countries.  So that drops right out.

And, a second group of legal immigrants, the Mexican seasonal workers in the US, for example, are actually needed by their host countries.  Get rid of all the Mexican workers on US farms and you'll see what happens to US farm output.  Increasing farmerworker pay in Mexico won't help with that.

This is also how the UK went through Brexit, had worker problems, and ended up with even [more legal immigrants than before](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2023/may/23/panic-immigration-brexit-wages-uk-economy).

> Some of this is normal. Anti-immigration politicians and lobby groups, and the Home Office, always complain the numbers are too high, while business, and other government departments such as the Treasury and the Department for Health, always want a more liberal system. But these longstanding conflicts have been brought into sharp relief by two things. First, the current state of the labour market, with labour demand high after the pandemic, and domestic labour supply constrained by the rise in ill health and early retirement. And the end of free movement was always going to reduce the flexibility of the UK labour market.

---

Now, as to the linked article (basically a Reddit page), I live in Canada and saw posters for the event.  It basically consisted of a **demanding that everyone, legal or not, gets residency status right away if they did not yet have it**.  Yes, well, good luck with that.  Canada is accepting a huge amount of immigrants, but it's mostly skill-based.  Trade agreement or no trade agreement, I rather fail to see what's in it for us at this point and again, these are not necessarily folk that are coming from countries that we have trade agreements with.  And, well, there is a process to obtain residency. I know, I went through it.

However, Canadian press does occasionally cover the work situation of seasonal workers, on Canadian farms, and there is [room for improvement](https://www.croptracker.com/blog/seasonal-farm-labor-issues-in-canada.html), without necessarily granting residency (like many countries, our residents, whether citizens or not, aren't that keen on fruit picking).

Comment: Perhaps workers in Vietnam vote, but they have only one party to choose from.

Comment: "required to have laws" doesn't necessarily mean that the laws are as progressive in the rich countries.

Comment: @Barmar Yup.  Stealing that ;-)

Comment: The question was "Have making worker standards part of trade deals been **tried**?", not "Have they worked well?"

Comment: This, of course, is a much more insightful answer than the top voted one. But the main problem with SE is IMHO not hounding off overly sensitive question askers, but the "fastest gun in the West" answer to questions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score -1):

TBH, I'm not sure what this Q is really about. But since the 2nd/final para says

> trade deals, like the EU [...] I'm not sure how much labor standards are part of it.

with respect to the EU. [FYI](https://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=157&langId=en):

> As regards labour law, the EU complements policy initiatives taken by individual EU countries by setting minimum standards. In accordance with the Treaty - particularly Article 153 - it adopts laws (directives) that set minimum requirements for
>
> - working & employment conditions,
> - informing & consulting workers.
>
> Individual EU countries are free to provide higher levels of protection if they so wish.

As random example I recall from the press, there have been recent debates about standards [adopted](https://www.politico.eu/article/trucker-rules-europe-logistics-monility-european-commission/) for truckers for instance. (Details of actual standards/adopted can found [on EU's site](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/work-abroad/rules-working-road-transport/index_en.htm), in that regard.)

---

As for the broader, title question, while someone gave a telegraphic answer linking to the ILO's database... the reality is that many developing countries [have resisted](https://www.brookings.edu/articles/workers-rights-labor-standards-and-global-trade/) stronger standards because that is/was ahem their competitive advantage:

> At the 1996 WTO ministerial meeting, developing countries strongly resisted efforts to allow the WTO to enforce labor standards, and the meeting concluded by affirming the ILO’s role in determining and dealing with labor standards. Similarly, when President Clinton and some EU leaders tried to bring workers’ rights into the next round of multilateral trade negotiations at the 1999 WTO ministerial meeting in Seattle, developing countries rejected the initiative.

And unlike the WTO, which can authorize retaliatory tariffs etc., the ILO [can do](https://www.brookings.edu/articles/workers-rights-labor-standards-and-global-trade/) little besides press releases to enforce its standards:

> Although the work of the ILO has been recognized with a Nobel Peace Prize, many labor sympathizers are skeptical that it can protect workers using its existing enforcement tools since they impose little penalty besides bad publicity.

As for other bilateral or multi-lateral treaties, at least the EU ([according](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/RegData/etudes/BRIE/2022/698800/EPRS_BRI(2022)698800_EN.pdf), ahem, to EPRS) has increasingly included such provisions in their treaties with other, non-EU countries.

> the one with South Korea (2011) being the first to contain a dedicated chapter. These provisions continue to evolve: for instance, recent agreements with some of the EU's developed partners, such as Canada and the United Kingdom, now include additional obligations on safety and health at work.

Generally speaking however, these just include reference to ILO standards. OTOH, there is more in such (EU external) treaties than bad publicity in terms of enforcement, i.e. there's usually some kind of arbitration provision included. As detailed therein, the EU exercised their right to invoke it in a dispute with South Korea, with the settlement decision coming out in 2021. (If you're curious as to the details, this was a two-pronged complaint. One prong was that South Korea was slow in ratifying some ILO conventions. This part of the complaint was actually rejected by the arbitration panel. The 2nd prong was more narrowly focused on the [too narrow, according to the EU] definition of "worker" in South Korean legislation. The arbitration panel agreed with the EU on this, and urged South Korea to change their legislation on that point.)

Comment: The EU is not a Trade Deal per se, so not sure this answers the Q.  Yes, it incorporates trade regulations but it is much more - including cession of national sovereignty in numerous matters - that using it as an example seems really stretching it.  Maybe the adjusted treaties that associate countries like Switzerland and Norway follow?  And even those are largely - "do like EU to have trade access", including contributing budget-wise.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: indeed but the OP seems unaware even of this, by their own account. IDK if they want answers to talk about the EU or some other "trade deals" since they don't explicitly mention any other. There's some rant about Canadian immigration/laws in the 1st para, which is also not a trade deal... OTOH the Q got tons of upvotes, not sure why, given its quality.

Comment: Mentioning the "rant" brings to mind that this was a new contributor.  Who is now an ex-contributor.  Surely the comments made could have been kinder IMHO.  They took an event to ask a reasonable question.  Now, the event chosen wasn't necessarily the best one, though it did relate.  And they were somewhat unclear and not great at references - which they did correct.  But did they need hounding out?  The core question was pretty solid and certainly caught the community's attention.